# IHttpContextAccessor to get the jwt token singleton

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, httpcontext

I am using the IHttpContextAccessor to get the jwt token, my question would be in dependency injection.

Searching I see many people using singleton, how does IHttpContext handle multiple requests being singleton?

If the application is serving 3 or more requests with different tokens, each request thread will have its correct jwt even if the instance is unique?

`services.AddScoped(x => new AuthToken(x.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor().HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["Authorization"]));`

Comment: The HttpContext isn't a singleton. The HttpContextAccessor is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-6.0).

It's how `HttpContextAccessor` is implemented, even being singleton it returns different values for different threads/requests. Answering your question, yes it's correct - Accessed `HttpContext` will be different in each request.